# Notation for a particular number

Tags: notation

The maximum value of $X$ is $Y$.

$Y \ge 0$

$Y$ is in increments of $1$.

How can I use a concise notation set to show the range of valid $X$ values?

Comment: I don't really understand your predicament... can you use standard interval notation? $X\in(a,b)$

Answer (score 1):

$X=\{x\in \mathbb{Z} \cap [0,y]: y\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{ 0 \} \}$